# Jenkins, running selenium tests on local dev machine

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server running in private cloud and the dev team want to be able to run some selenium tests on their local dev rigs.

I've looked at Selenium Grid and installed the Selenium Grid plugin for Jenkins and whilst I can get nodes to register to the Jenkins server (Selenium Hub) I cannot invoke tests on the node.

The local dev machines are on our corporate network behind a firewall with no option for that to be changed.

Does the Selenium Hub try to make a new connection to the node when it needs to, or does it/can it use the connection initiated by the node as some kind of reverse tunnel?